# Как скрывать и показывать кнопку в зависимости от версии операционной системы?

Tags: html

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли какой-нибудь способ скрывать и показывать кнопку по id в зависимости от того, windows или MAC OS используя html.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого следует использовать `window.navigator`:
[Вопрос на английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-details-using-javascript)

```js
let OSName = "Unknown"
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 10.0")!= -1) OSName="Windows 10"
else if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 6.3") != -1) OSName="Windows 8.1"
else if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 6.2") != -1) OSName="Windows 8"
else if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 6.1") != -1) OSName="Windows 7"
else if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 6.0") != -1) OSName="Windows Vista"
else if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 5.1") != -1) OSName="Windows XP"
else if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 5.0") != -1) OSName="Windows 2000"
else if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mac")            != -1) OSName="Mac/iOS"
else if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("X11")            != -1) OSName="UNIX"
else if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Linux")          != -1) OSName="Linux"

console.log(OSName)

if (OSName == "Windows 10") {
  // Сделать что-то
}
else if (OSName == "Mac/iOS") {
   // Сделать что-то другое 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вызов `window.navigator`:

```js
console.log(window.navigator.platform);
```

Вот тут подробнее: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9514476